# Find a general solution PDE $(x^2+3y^2+3u^2)u_x-2xyu_y+2xu=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> $(x^2+3y^2+3u^2)u_x-2xyu_y+2xu=0$

This is my solution;

${\frac {dx}{x^2+3y^2+3u^2}}$=${\frac {dy}{-2xy}}$=${\frac {du}{-2xu}}$= $λ$

${\frac {dy}{-2xy}}$=${\frac {du}{-2xu}}$

${\frac {du}{u}}$-${\frac {dy}{y}}$=$0$

$lnu-lny=lnc_1$

${\frac {u}{y}}$=$c_1$

then i know that we now need to ﬁnd another function. but i am stuck.

$F(c_1,c_2)=0$

$c_1=f(c_2)$

can u help me to find $c_2$ with steps, please?  i would appreciate it if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2xy dx + (x^2+3y^2+\dfrac{3}{c^2}y^2) dy = {d\phi}= 0$

${d\phi}=c_2$

${\phi}(x,y,u)=x^2y+y^3+yu^2$=$c_2$